# App Engine with Maven sources and javadoccs

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

I created a Maven App Engine project with the official plugin as written [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven). My problem is that sources and/or javadocs are not getting attached for App Engine libraries. I use [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.appengine%7Cappengine-api-1.0-sdk%7C1.8.8%7Cjar) artifact as a dependecy, but it only provides the binaries. However [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.appengine%7Cappengine-java-sdk%7C1.8.8%7Czip) artifact which is bundled into a big zip, has javadocs and sources. If i add this to pom.xml, it says *"missing artifact"*. Is there any way to use this?